# Magento 2 : category Url Rewrite to Cms page

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to rewrite an URL from category to CMS page, but it didn't work. When I try to delete the system category URL and rewrite a custom URL then it works, but after indexing I'm facing the same issue.

So please can you help me how to rewrite an URL from category to CMS page which remains after indexing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy: works for Magento 2.2.1 but I am sure it works for other versions too.

Log into the backend.
Go to Catalog -> Choose the category you would like to direct to the CMS.
Now go to the very bottom of the page: Menu->Custom URL.
Enter the key for the CMS block you created in to the Custom URL box.
Clean the cache and browser history and reload the page.

You should be now directed to whatever CMS page you just targeted.

Comment: Please consider improving the formatting of your answer. Paragraphs help with readability!

Answer (score 1):

To @Luke Pulaski
In default magento 2.2.1 there is no such option, you are probably using the custom module which generates that field